# C++ can't populate data

Tags: c++

I am trying to populate my vectors with x and y values. but it doesn't seems to add on but just override the 
first.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "Point.h"

using namespace std;
int x,y;
Point point;
string options;
void someMethods();
int main()
{   
    cout << "Please Enter x-Cordinate"<< endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Please Enter y-Cordinate" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    cout << "Enter cords again? yes/no"<< endl;
    cin >> options;
    while (options == "yes") {

        cout << "Please Enter x-Cordinate"<< endl;
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Please Enter y-Cordinate" << endl;
        cin >> y;
        cout << "Enter cords again? yes/no"<< endl;
        cin >> options;
    }


    if(options == "no") {
        Point Point(x,y);
        Point.someMethods();
       // break;
    }
}
```

Point.h

```
#ifndef Point_Point_h
#define Point_Point_h
#include <vector>

class Point {
private:
      int x,y;

public : 

      Point() {
       x = 0;
       y = 0;
      } //default consrructor


      Point(int x,int y);
      int getX();
      int getY();
      void setX(int x);
      void setY(int y);
      std::vector<Point> storeData;
      void someMethods();

};    

#endif
```

Point.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
using namespace std;


Point::Point(int x,int y) {
setX(x);
setY(y);

}  

int Point::getX() {
  return x;
}
int Point::getY() {
  return y;
}

void Point::setX(int x) {
this->x = x;
}

void Point::setY(int y) {
this->y = y;
}


void Point::someMethods() {
x = getX();
y = getY();

Point Point(x,y);
storeData.push_back(Point);

   for (int i=0; i<storeData.size(); i++) {
    cout << "X "<< storeData[i].getX() <<"Y " << storeData[i].getY() << endl;
   }
// do some methods here after getting the x and y cords;
}
```

how can I make it such that e.g(I enter x and y 3 times let's say 1,1 2,2 3,3 )

then it will output

```
X: 1,Y: 1
X: 2,Y: 2
X: 3,Y: 3
```

Comment: It's because you *are* overriding the first values - the data is output only after the last time you enter it. Additionally, are you familiar with the `do..while` loop? It'd be useful here.

Comment: New to C++? Some basic pointers: avoid `using namespace std;`, avoid global variables, and Get/Set methods are not used as much as in some other languages (like Java).

Comment: yes I am new to C++ and I slowly learning it

Comment: Please avoid things like "Point Point(x,y);" - eg make the second Point lower case

Comment: This code is very confused. I think you should start again. It looks like code where you wrote something fairly sensible to start with but when it didn't work you've just added more and more making it more and more of a mess. But here's a clue, when you want something to happen more than once you put it in a loop. In your code you ask questions inside your while loop but you don't add anything to your vector inside your while loop. So therefore you don't add more than one value to your vector.

Comment: Save some repetition; use a `do{...}while(true);`

Comment: Another point, it really doesn't make sense to have a Point class and then have a vector of Points inside the Point class. Make them separate. A Point should have x and y only, the vector should be somewhere else entirely.

Comment: thanks for all your advise and help

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    // don't need global variables, just define local ones here
    int x,y;
    Point point;
    string options;

    // You shouldn't store the vector of Points in the Point class itself.
    // It doesn't have anything to do with a Point. classes should generally
    // only contain relevant information (ex. Point contains only x and y coords).
    vector<Point> pointsVector;

    // do-while will do the contents of the loop at least once
    // it will stop when the while condition is no longer met
    do
    {
        cout << "Please Enter x-Cordinate"<< endl;
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Please Enter y-Cordinate" << endl;
        cin >> y;

        pointsVector.push_back(Point(x, y));

        cout << "Enter cords again? yes/no"<< endl;
        cin >> options;
    } while (options == "yes")

    // don't really need to check if options is "no"
    // if you have exited the do/while loop above, the assumption is that you don't 
    // want to enter more coordinates.
    doSomethingWithTheVectorOfPoints(pointsVector);

    return 0;
}
```

In the function *doSomethingWithTheVectorOfPoints*, you can place the code for outputting the X and Y coordinates. (You can also just loop through the vector in the main function directly instead.)

Also, you could add a member function to your Point class called ToString or Print to do the work for you.

**Edit**: I didn't actually compile this, it's just to give you an idea of how you could rewrite your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should have:

- No global variables
- A point class supporting stream input (output)
- The stored data out of the point class (why should a poor point manage that?)
- Stream input with validation.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, Point& point) {
    return in >> point.x >> point.y;
}

typedef std::vector<Point> PointStorage;

int main()
{
    PointStorage point_storage;
    Point point;
    while(true) {
        std::cout << "Please enter X and Y xordinates or 'no' to stop input" << std::endl;
        std::string line;
        if( ! std::getline(std::cin, line))
            throw std::invalid_argument(line);
        else {
            std::istringstream point_input(line);
            // Skip leading white spaces, read a point, skip trailing white apace
            // and ensure no additional character is left.
            if(point_input >> point >> std::ws && point_input.eof()) {
                point_storage.push_back(point);
            }
            else {
                std::string no;
                std::istringstream no_input(line);
                // Skip leading white spaces, read "no", skip trailing white apace
                // and ensure no additional character is left.
                if(no_input >> no >> std::ws && no_input.eof() && no == "no") {
                    break;
                }
                throw std::invalid_argument(line);
            }
        }
    }
    for(PointStorage::const_iterator pos = point_storage.begin();
        pos != point_storage.end();
        ++pos)
    {
        std::cout << pos->x << ", " << pos->y << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Throwing exceptions is likely a bad decision, but it simplifies the example.

Answer (score -1):

You *re-create* your `Point` object with the final coords every time you enter "no". This is why you only keep the last pair.

On an unrelated note, you should probably simplify the code significantly. There is no reason for `Point` object to keep a vector of `Point` objects in the first place. You probably want to keep a history/sequence of raw coordinates there and have something like:

```
Point mypt;

while (options == "yes") {
    mypt.AddCoords(x, y);
    // read more coords/options
}

// do stuff on filled mypt object
```